# Prevent select option from changing back to default

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page that has 6 options in a drop down menu. I use the below code to make the default select option "Full Name"

```
       $(function(){
         $('select option[value="Full Name"]').attr("selected",true);
       });
```

this works fine however since the page is called on itself and I change the option to search for Team for example, when the page loads the default option will obviously change back to Full Name. I need to change it back to what was previously selected.

This sounds easy to do and I'm just coming up with a blank at the moment.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The default option will usually be the first or whatever is set by the server. Since this is doing a trip to the sever, why not set it at the server? More robust than doing it client side and no scripting required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to store the state of the dropdown either using server or client side technology.

In client side you can use a cookie or html5 storage like [local storage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute) to store the selected value and when the page is revisited and there is a stored value then you can select that value instead of the default value

If you are planning to use cookie to store the information, then you can think of a jQuery plugin like [this](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) or [this](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.cookie)

An abstract implementation might look like

```
$('select').change(function(){
    storeValue('mykey', $(this).val());
})

function storeValue(key, value){
    $.cookie(key, value)
}

function getValue(key){
    return $.cookie(key);
}

$(function(){
    var val = getValue('mykey') || 'Full Name';
    $('select option[value="' + val + '"]').prop("selected",true);
});
```