# JQuery UI Tabs - how to remain in a last selected tab on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery

JQuery UI Tabs -

How to remain in a last selected tab on page refresh

Comment: Use to example cookies, session or url address, hash.

Answer (score 0):

You need to preserve the selected tab either using a server side technology like database or using client side storage like cookie/localstorage

You can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016250/prevent-select-option-from-changing-back-to-default/17016298#17016298) to a similar question using cookies

```
$('select').change(function(){
    storeValue('mykey', $(this).val());
})

function storeValue(key, value){
    $.cookie(key, value)
}

function getValue(key){
    return $.cookie(key);
}

$(function(){
    var val = getValue('mykey') || 'Full Name';
    $('select option[value="' + val + '"]').prop("selected",true);
});
```